# How to split a single XML file into multiple based on tags

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have an XML file that have tags. I want to split files like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMPRMART CREATION_DATE="08/20/2018 18:06:44" REPOSITORY_VERSION="187.96">
<REPOSITORY NAME="REP_DEV" VERSION="187" CODEPAGE="UTF-8" DATABASETYPE="Sybase">
<FOLDER NAME="MC_DEV" 
    <CONFIG DESCRIPTION ="Default ORDER configuration object" ISDEFAULT ="YES" NAME ="default_ORDER_config" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Advanced" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </CONFIG>
    <ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Normal" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>
    <ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Medium" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>
    <ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Advanced" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>
    <LOCATION DESCRIPTION ="" ISENABLED ="YES" 
    </LOCATION>
</FOLDER>
</REPOSITORY>
</EMPRMART>
```

Below is the code tried . But it is generating every single line into a new file

```
awk  '
    BEGIN { RS = "</ORDER>" } 
    $0 ~ /[^[:blank:]\n]/ { 
        printf "%s\n", $0 RS >> FILENAME "_" ++i ".xml" 
    }
' test.xml
```

I want to split this file based on ORDER tags alone as mentioned below

```
File1.xml
    <ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Normal" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>        
File2.xml
    <ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Medium" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>
File3.xml
<ORDER DESCRIPTION ="" ISVALID ="YES" 
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Advanced" VALUE =""/>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME ="Order type" VALUE ="NO"/>
    </ORDER>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. The nodes with node-name `ORDER` are not closed. The same for `FOLDER` and `LOCATION` You are missing the `>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
awk '/<ORDER/{f=1; out="file_"(++c)".xml"} f{print > out} /<\/ORDER>/{close(out); f=0}' file
```

it's obviously fragile as it's just doing regexp matches against text, not parsing the XML, but it'll work for the sample you posted and any similar text.

Answer (score 7):

To achieve what you request, I would not make use of awk, but rather a good XML-parser such as xmlstarlet or xmlint. There is a single unknown here, and that is the total amount of nodes with the name `ORDER`. We could write down an advanced XPath for the selection, but we will keep it simple:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//ORDER)' file.xml
```

Now that you have the count, you can loop over all cases and write them to the files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xmlfile=file.xml

n=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//ORDER)' file.xml)
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
   xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//ORDER[${i}]" -c . $xmlfile > "File${i}.xml"
done
```

Comment: xmlstarlet this utility is not installed.

Comment: If you download cygwin for windows, there is an option to include the xmlstarlet package. This is what I did. Just make sure you select the 'Full' option of the View dropdown...

Comment: Really handy script. I needed the content of a specific element, which was easy with: `xmlstarlet sel -t -value-of "//ORDERS[${i}]/ORDERFIELD" $xmlfile`

Answer (score 5):

If you do use `gnu awk` this should give your requested result.

```
awk '/<ORDER>/ {f=1;++a} f {print > "file_"a".xml"} /<\/ORDER>/ {f=0}' file
```

It will print only lines from `<ORDER>` to `</ORDER>` as a section in files called `file_1.xml`, `file_2.xml` etc.