# How to split a single XML files into multiple XML files based on a given tag and renamed based that tag attribute?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I have several big archives in XML that I need to split the main node into files, and use the node's title attribute as name, eg:

```xml
<book title="ABC123" year="2000">
  <description>Some sentences...</description>
  <img src="image/cover_ABC123" />
</book>
```

And export it as `ABC123.xml`

I found a script that partially solves my help request, but it follows a numbered sequence and export files as 01.xml, 02.xml etc.; I would need to adapt it to my case, but I can't figure how:

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889282/17486393)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xmlfile=file.xml

n=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//ORDER)' file.xml)
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
   xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//ORDER[${i}]" -c . $xmlfile > "File${i}.xml"
done
```

I tried to add this option: `-e "title"` to extract also the name:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
xmlfile=file.xml

n=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(//book -e "title")' file.xml)
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
   xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//ORDER book -e "title"[${i}]" -c . $xmlfile > "File${i}.xml"
done
```

But I get:

`xsl:for-each : could not compile select expression '//product -e title [1]`

I tried to use this one instead, but I didn't understand this as well:

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/36156617/17486393)

```
$ for ((i=1; i<=`xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/root/row)'  1.xml`; i++)); do \
          echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>' > NAME.xml;
          NAME=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/root/row[position()='$i']' -v './NAME' 1.xml); \
          xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/root/row[position()='$i']' -c . -n 1.xml >> $NAME.xml; \
          echo '</root>' >> NAME.xml
       done
```

And I changed into:

```bash
$ for ((i=1; i<=`xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'count(/root/book)'  books01.xml`; i++)); do \
          NAME=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/root/book[position()='$i']' -v './NAME' books01.xml); \
          xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/root/book[position()='$i']' -c . -n books01.xml >> $NAME.xml;
       done
```

It doesn't produce any files...

If possible I'd like to use xmlstarlet.

Comment: Please, make the question a [mcve] by adding a minimum XML working input and output samples and also adding the specific code you have tried. CAn be done with `xmllint` too

Comment: Sorry I tried my best, is confused because I am even more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 or later:

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
      
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="//book">
        <xsl:result-document href="{@title}.xml">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

To execute this with SaxonJ from the command line (on one line):

```
java -jar dir/SaxonHE12-3J/saxon-he-12.3.jar 
  net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:input.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xsl 
  -o:out/output.xml -t
```

The resulting `output.xml` file will be essentially empty; the multiple files produced by xsl:result-document will be in the same directory as output.xml. The -t option logs each output file as it is written.

If you prefer a GUI tool, many popular XML editors have Saxon (or another XSLT 2.0 processor) integrated.

Comment: Could you explain how I should use it? I have been reading this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT but I haven't understood how practically use it...

Comment: Web browsers only support XSLT 1.0, this requires XSLT 2.0. There are a number of XSLT processors supporting XSLT 2.0 or later but my company's product, Saxon is probably the most popular. Follow the download links at www.saxonica.com (Download / Java / Saxon-HE) and then run it from the command line as explained at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline . Since you're new to this I'll edit the answer to add the XSLT boilerplate so you have a complete working stylesheet.

Comment: Now I understood why `xalan` and `xsltproc` didn't work they support only up to 1.1...

Comment: Thank you Michael. All this XML stuff is very lacking on Linux, perhaps it depends by the fact the in early 2000 Windows was the only dominant platform, also for development, while Linux was just an infant...

Answer (score 0):

> If possible I'd like to use xmlstarlet

`xmlstarlet` supports the
[`EXSLT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exslt)
[`exsl:document`](https://exslt.github.io/exsl/elements/document/index.html)
element which is used to create multiple result documents in an
existing directory, for example:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh
cat <<'HERE' | xmlstarlet transform \
  /dev/stdin -s outDir="${TMPDIR}" input.xml
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
>
  <xsl:param name="outDir" select="'/tmp'"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//book">
      <exsl:document 
        href="{concat($outDir,'/',translate(@title,'/','_'),'.xml')}" 
        method="xml" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="no"
      >
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </exsl:document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
HERE
```

where

- `xmlstarlet transform` is an
  [XSLT processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Processor_implementations)
- the XSLT stylesheet is read from `stdin`
- the output directory can be passed on the command line,
  e.g. `${TMPDIR}` or `file://${TMPDIR}`
- any `/` (slash) characters in the book title are replaced with
  `_` (underscore)
- if book titles are not unique only the last will survive
- the XPath 1.0 functions `concat` and `translate` are documented
  [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-concat) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#function-translate)

---

Or, if you're confident that lines in the input XML file are
relatively short and therefore handled by standard text tools
(hint: `getconf LINE_MAX`), you could have `xmlstarlet select`
add a delimiter line before each XML `<book>` section and use
[`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk)
to split the output into separate files:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh
delim=$(uuidgen)
xmlstarlet select -t \
  -m '//book' \
    -o "${delim}$(printf '\t')${TMPDIR}/" -v 'translate(@title,"/","_")' -o '.xml' -n \
    -c '.' -n \
input.xml |
awk -F'[\t\n]' -v sep="${delim}" '$1==sep{close(out);out=$2;next;}{print>out;}'
```